# Factory Girl attribute create vs build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to run some RSpec tests using FactoryGirl.

I have a card model that can be in one of the following states:
NEW, ACTIVE, INACTIVE, which I have numbered 0, 1 and 2, respectively.

I have defined my card and active_card factories as such:

```
factory :card do
  sequence(:uid) { |n| "UID_#{n}" }
  state Card::NEW

  factory :active_card do
    state Card::ACTIVE
    activated_at { Faker::Time.between(12.months.ago, 9.months.ago) }
  end
end
```

In my tests, I have tried:

```
card = create(:active_card)
```

and my debug statement

```
puts card.to_json
```

spits out that the state attribute of card is equal to 0 (NEW).

When I try,

```
card = build(:active_card),
```

the state attribute of card is equal to 1 (ACTIVE) as expected.

Does anyone know why I get the wrong value for state when I persist the data to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of:

```
card = build(:active_card)
```

you've just gotten built, and **not saved** active record to db, so the field `state` is quite fully controlled by factory declaration, but in case:

```
card = create(:active_card)
```

you've gotten built, and **saved** to db the active record. So the field `state`, could be changed by state machine, validation, or any other code of that model. Just make thin in your mind.

Comment: Many thanks! I had the following hook in my card model:
`before_validation :initialize_state, on: :create` which set the state to Card::NEW.

I just had to call to my Card#skip_initialization_state! method in before(:create) in my factory definition.

Thanks again!